# Progress Bar in Spotfire Text Area

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to implement Progress bar in Spotfire Text Area taking the below link as reference

https://community.tibco.com/questions/has-anyone-been-able-invoke-progress-bar-or-some-other-method-alert-user-action-being

I am getting the data as expected but once the data is loaded in client, Spotfire seems to be crashing.

When I opened the same in web then it is giving me the data but the Progress bar doesn't seems to be disappearing even after the data is loaded.

Is there a way to implement Progress bar in Spotfire as I have many On Demand tables in my visualization and the users are requesting for a progress bar to get a track whether the data is refreshed or not.

Thanks in Advance for Clarifying.

San

Error popped up after crashing:

TIBCO® Spotfire® Analyst 7.11.1 LTS HF-008 R163844
Build version: 7.11.1.0.13
Build date: 6/28/2018

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: global name 'vis' is not defined
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.GetVariable(CodeContext context, String name, Boolean isGlobal, Boolean lightThrow)
   at IronPython.Compiler.LookupGlobalInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget3(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable.d__a5.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.ExternalColumnProducer.d__37.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.DataFunctionImpl.<>c__DisplayClassf.b__e()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.InvocationAttempt.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.InvocationAttempt.WaitUntilPerformed()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.PerformInvocation(ApplicationInvocation applicationInvocation, Boolean shallBeSynchronous)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsApplicationThread.Invoke(ApplicationInvocation method)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Threading.WorkItem.ReturnItem()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.DataFunctionImpl.ResultHandler_(DataFunctionWorkItem workItem)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Threading.WorkItem.ReturnItem()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Threading.Worker`2.DoBatchWorkCore(IList`1 workItems)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Snapshot`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ReadCore>b__5()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.ThreadTransactionInfo.EvaluateWithGenerationDependant(ILimitationTarget generationDependant, Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Snapshot`1.ReadCore(Action`1 action)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Snapshot`1.Read(Action`1 action)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Threading.WorkItem.ReadModel[TModel](Action`1 readAction)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Threading.Worker`2.HandleWorkItemsCore(IList`1 workItems)

Comment: `global name 'vis' is not defined at IronPython`... do you have an IPython script running with a parameter not defined?

Comment: Hi Mark.. Thanks for your response.. parameter vis is defined in my dashboard and I am getting the refreshed data as well. The problem is Spotifre is crashing once the data is refreshed.